# Generate randomly placed squares with javaFX

Tags: javafx

I am trying to figure out how I can generate randomly placed squares using javaFX.  I have the following code started, however it does not function properly.
The loop appears to run only one time, as the stage is called.  I can't wrap my head around how to run the loop, and then call the stage.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Testing extends Application{
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

       for(int i=0; i<=30;i++) {
           float x = (float)(Math.random()*513);
           float y = (float)(Math.random()*513);

           Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,40,40);
           Group root = new Group(r);
           Scene scene = new Scene(root, 512, 512, Color.WHITE);
           primaryStage.setTitle("Assignment 5, a QR Code");
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.show();
       }

       //Group root = new Group(r);
       //Scene scene = new Scene(root, 512, 512, Color.WHITE);

       //primaryStage.setTitle("Assignment 5, a QR Code");
       //primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       //primaryStage.show();
   }
   public static void main (String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: You create a new group and a new scene, and replace the stage's scene in every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @James_D said you got the `Scene`, `Group`, and `Stage` in the loop. Move them out. **Update:** Also, like @James_D pointed out the `List` is not really needed. Just add the `Rectangles` to the `Group`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication42 extends Application {  
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        Group root = new Group();
        for(int i=0; i<=30;i++) 
        {
           float x = (float)(Math.random()*513);
           float y = (float)(Math.random()*513);

           Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,40,40);
           root.getChildren().add(r);//Add each rectangle to the Group.
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 512, 512, Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Assignment 5, a QR Code");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }        
}
```

[image]